# Calculate average formula of random numbers

Tags: linear-algebra

I have array of $N$ random numbers between $\min$ to $\max$. I am building a $2$ dimension graph where $Y$ dimension are the array numbers, and $X$ dimension are neutral numbers from $0$ to $N$.

How can I find the formula of straight line that will be at minimum distance from all the points on the graph?

For example:

- Input: array = $[8.001, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20.001]$, $\min = 8.001$, $\max = 20.001$
- Output: $y = 2x + 8$; $\min = 8$; $\max = 20$

*Notice that input $min$ is not equal to output $min$.*

Comment: I found this related article interesting : (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) the average of evenly distributed random numbers is the average of the possibilities.

Comment: @YiyuanLee what about calculating the min and max?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I don't miss a thing, you're looking for [Linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression). Take a look at the section [Estimation methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression#Estimation_methods) and also at the article [Ordinary least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares) (the section [Estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Estimation) in particular) to find out the concrete algorithms.

If you're interested in a numerical estimation, any Matlab-like package will do that very easy. For [Scilab](http://www.scilab.org/) see [reglin](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.4.1/en_US/reglin.html) documentation page.

Comment: It's not exactly what I meant, but I think you helped me to ask a more proper question now. So I will in a moment.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/726039/calculate-linear-regression-segment